# What parts of the ending may change?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Just like in BotW, the ending is probably modular, lots of things may or may not be there depending if you did something or not. (Staying vague so if someone that hasn't finished the game opens this page by accident, there is not spoilers before the fold)

So in the ending, what scenes happen or doesn't happen depending on a trigger, and what are those triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://gamewith.net/zelda-totk/article/show/39218)<sup>Spoilers ahead</sup> guide, there are two endings available: The "Normal" ending and the "True" ending.

Based on the guide, no matter your play style, the "normal" ending will always play once you have defeated the final boss. However, if you have completed every main quest, the "True" ending, which is a 6-minute post-credit cutscene, will play.